# Unable to add page numbers in text conversion from word using win32ole

Tags: ms-word, win32ole

I am trying to add page numbers for each page in WORD document using win32ole in ruby. Please see the following code

```
require 'win32ole'
word = WIN32OLE.new("Word.Application")
word.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 9  #wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
word.Selection.Add(selection.Range,wdFieldNumPages)
```

The above code was able to add page numbers and when i open the doc file i am seeing page numbers added at the header of each page but while converting to text file it is not preserving headers and footers and it was adding page number only for last page.

```
doc.SaveAs("#{doc_output_path}.txt",4)
```

Can anyone help me correcting where i am doing wrong. Or if there is any other way to add page number information please tell me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Text file (.txt) doesn't have 'header/footer' sections therefore you can't keep it within text. In other words, page numbers are overwritten by text. Possibly this is the reason why the last page number is kept after conversion (nothing to be overwritten).